# VIM: hi IncSearch - why are the colors swapped?

Tags: vim, colors

This is how I set up Search and IncSearch options in my VIM configuration:

```
hi Search               guifg=black   guibg=yellow  
hi IncSearch            guifg=black   guibg=yellow
```

The question is: why VIM does not respect "IncSearch" setting and swaps the colors? Check the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtFGK.png) from my environment.

If I manually swap the colors, like this:

```
hi IncSearch            guifg=yellow   guibg=black
```

I finally get yellow background and black text for incremental search.

*Using VIM 7.4 on Windows 7 64bit.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:hi` command *adds* to the set of attributes already associated with the specified group. By default, the IncSearch group includes `gui=reverse`. Therefore, when you specified `guifg=black` and `guibg=yellow`, Vim reversed those to make the foreground yellow and the background black. To fix that, you can add `gui=NONE` to your highlight group specifications, e.g.,

```
:hi Search    gui=NONE guifg=black guibg=yellow
:hi IncSearch gui=NONE guifg=black guibg=yellow
```

Comment: Perfect, that was it. Thank you so much! :-)